# nginx ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from my ip

Tags: nginx, iptables

i manage a VPS with some sites inside, running on nginx.
Browsing a website from my wifi i get this error "www.[website].com non ha inviato dati. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". The rest of the world view the website.

I can login into SSH, i can ping the server

```
iptables -L INPUT -v -n

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 4 packets, 160 bytes) pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
256M   26G fail2ban-nginx-noscript  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
256M   26G fail2ban-nginx-badbots  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
256M   26G fail2ban-wordpress-soft  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
256M   26G fail2ban-wordpress-hard  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
4058  218K fail2ban-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587
256M   26G fail2ban-nginx-http-auth  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
7612  405K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
266M   30G ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
266M   30G ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
456K   24M ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
231K   13M ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
231K   13M ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
231K   13M ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

my ip is not listed

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

no blocking of my ip listed on the logs

browsing  website from my 4G mobile phone works

browsing from my wifi ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

clearing cache or change browser from my wifi ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

incredible ....